# How to use the FindElements command correctly?

Tags: c#, selenium

Below I have three dive tags that all have the same class:

```
<div class="confirmation-price-summary__price-label confirmation-price-summary__price-label--with-dropdown">(2) Seats</div>

<div class="confirmation-price-summary__price-label confirmation-price-summary__price-label--with-dropdown">(2) Meals</div>


<div class="confirmation-price-summary__price-label confirmation-price-summary__price-label--with-dropdown firefinder-match">(1) Extra Baggage</div>
```

I create a variable to point to the all of those class elements via xpath in my 'confirmationResponsiveElements.cs' page:

```
public static By TravelEssentialsBasketLabels => By.XPath("//*[@class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label confirmation-price-summary__price-label--with-dropdown']");
```

I want to use the 'FindElements' method to find all of these elements and then assert that they contain 'Seats', 'Meals' and 'Extra Baggage'. However I am not sure how to use this correctly as it's giving me the red line of death:

```
public void TravelEssentialsLabelsSideBasket()
   => _driver.FindElements(ConfirmationResponsiveElements.TravelEssentialsBasketLabels).ToString();
```

What is the corret way to use FindElements and also, how can `Assert.IsTrue` should be written if I want to check that it contains 'Seats' , 'Meals' and 'Extra Baggage'?

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `_driver`? If it's the interface `IWebDriver` then you do not have those methods (you may use `RemoteWebDriver` directly).

Comment: findElements returns list of web elements. So you have to iterate each element and using GetText method. get the value of each element and compare it with expected value.

Comment: @Murthi Can you show an example on how this can be done please?

Comment: please check reply in answer section. It may contains typo as i am not much familiar with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> actualoptions = new List<string>();
List<string> expectedoptions = new List<string>();

expectedoptions.Add("Seats");
expectedoptions.Add("Meals");
expectedoptions.Add("Extra Baggage");

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label confirmation-price-summary__price-label--with-dropdown']"));

foreach(IWebElement link in links)
{
    string text = link.Text;
    actualoptions.Add(text);
}

//then you compare this list with expected value
if(String.SequenceEqual(actualoptions ,expectedoptions)){
    console.write("matching");
 else
   console.write("not matching");
```